# Index rebuild - Not reducing fragmentation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with nearly 18 million records and it has nearly 14 indexes including a clustered index.

One of the non-clustered index has a fragmentation level of 97%, so when I tried to rebuild the index - fragmentation level goes down to 96% or 94%. But, it is not reducing any further. Few details about the index,

Key columns: 2 (Includes clustered index column)

- Col 1 - nvarchar(255) – Clustered index column
- Col 2 - nchar(16)

Included columns: 2

- Col 1 - smallint
- Col 2 - smallint

Pages: 143539 
Index size: 1.3 GB 
Fill factor: 90 
Row locks: True 
Page locks: False 
Pad index: False

Any ideas why fragmentation level is not reducing?

Comment: Show us the table definition and index definition. You can change the column names if you want to.

Comment: @RandolphWest - Table has 72 columns, so I just updated the above post  with columns used in the index

Comment: Try rebuilding with maxdop 1.

Comment: What command did you use to rebuild the index? What is the index definition?

Comment: @kin Thanks kin. It did worked for me after using maxdop 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be due to MAXDOP setting on your server instance. It has been proven that [Online Index Rebuild – Can Cause Increased Fragmentation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2012/09/05/how-it-works-online-index-rebuild-can-cause-increased-fragmentation/) when it is allowed to run with MAX DOP > 1 and ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF directives.

If you are seeing this behavior, then its better to use (`MAXDOP 1`) (**serial index rebuild**) at query level when rebuilding index.

e.g.

> Alter Index all On test2 Rebuild With (maxdop = 1)

Refer to : [How It Works: MAX DOP Level and Parallel Index Builds](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2015/03/02/how-it-works-max-dop-level-and-parallel-index-builds/)

Comment: After your earlier comment (on Oct 15), I did referred to exactly those two links which you mentioned here. It did worked. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be not enough contiguous free space inside the database to arrange the index consecutively.  A work around to a very large index that won't defragment, one solution is to pre-size a new database and move all your objects to that DB, then recreate your indexes there as this will surely do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, but copying the database isn't viable for me at this moment.